# Expanded Raisebutton flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make the below two raised button fill the available width evenly.

[image]

My Column:

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:18.0),
              child: Text(
                'Which language Do you prefer',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 150.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                    child: Text('French'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 150.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                    child: Text('English'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                )
```

Has a gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ButtonTheme` inherits colors from [ThemeData](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html). Change colors or use a [MaterialButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html).

*Tip: Wrap your buttons in an [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.*

Answer (score -2):

add "crossAxisAlignment" propriety to the row that holds the tow buttons

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```